# Dagger 2 - Module Provide Singleton with

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger2 with Android and I came across the problem of how to build building Singleton using named variants.

Let's Say for my example that I want to build object C from B and A. A is not describe here but B has two version (niceB and notNiceB). I want to build C with notNiceB, how can I specify which bean to inject. @Named("notNiceB") B b in the parameters does not seem to work.

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
C providesC(B b, A a) {
    // Omitted here
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("niceB")
B providesNiceB() {
    // Omitted here
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("notNiceB")
B providesNotNiceB() {
    // Omitted here
}
}
```

Comment: EpicPandaForce has it correct below. Since you mention that it "does not seem to work", can you please add any error messages or other details that might help us debug?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Provides
@Singleton
C c(@Named("notNiceB") B b, A a) {
    // Omitted here
}
```

This should work.